# How to convert the script from using command,read to command,cut?

Tags: linux, shell

Here is the test sample:

```
test_catalog,test_title,test_type,test_artist
```

And i can use the following sript to cut off the text above by comma and set the variable respectively:

```
IFS=","
read cdcatnum cdtitle cdtype cdac < $temp_file
```

(ps:and the $temp_file is the dir of the test sample)

And if i want to replace the read with command,cut.Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many solutions:

```
line=$(head -1 "$temp_file")
echo $line | cut -d, ...
```

or

```
cut -d, ... <<< "$line"
```

or you can tell BASH to copy the line into an array:

```
typeset IFS=,
set -A ARRAY $(head -1 "$temp_file")
# use it
echo $ARRAY[0] # test_catalog
echo $ARRAY[1] # test_title
...
```

I prefer the array solution because it gives you a distinct data type and clearly communicates your intent. The echo/cut solution is also somewhat slower.

**[EDIT]** On the other hand, the `read` command splits the line into individual variables which gives each value a name. Which is more readable: `$ARRAY[0]` or `$cdcatnum`?

If you move columns around, you will just need to rearrange the arguments to the `read` command - if you use arrays, you will have to update all the array indices which you **will** get wrong.

Also `read` makes it much more simple to process the whole file:

```
while read cdcatnum cdtitle cdtype cdac ; do
    ....
done < "$temp_file"
```

Comment: Well,anyway,i think read is the best way.And i think if i use the cut command via ur way,i think i should split the word one by one.Yes?

Comment: Yes, `cut` can always only return a single result.

Answer (score 0):

man cut ?

But seriously, if you have something that works, why do you want to change it?
Personally, I'd probably use awk or perl to manipulate CSV files in linux.